# Why writing reverse iterator can affect whether an iterator is random-access-iterator or not?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I wanna write a container with random-access-iterator:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <concepts>

namespace foo
{
    struct container
    {
        struct iter
        {
            using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
            using pointer = int*;
            using reference = int&;
            using value_type = int;
            using iterator_category = ::std::random_access_iterator_tag;

            iter& operator++();
            iter operator++(int);
            iter& operator--();
            iter operator--(int);

            iter operator+(difference_type) const;
            iter operator-(difference_type) const;
            iter& operator+=(difference_type);
            iter& operator-=(difference_type);
            bool operator==(const iter&) const;
            bool operator!=(const iter&) const;
            bool operator<(const iter&) const;
            bool operator>(const iter&) const;
            bool operator<=(const iter&) const;
            bool operator>=(const iter&) const;
            difference_type operator-(const iter&) const;

            int& operator*() const;
            int& operator[](difference_type) const;
        };

        // code for reverse iterator, now it is comment out

        /* using riter = std::reverse_iterator<iter>;

        iter end();
        riter rbegin()
        {
            return std::reverse_iterator(this->end());
        }
        */
    };

    inline container::iter operator+(container::iter::difference_type, const container::iter&);
}

int main(void)
{
    static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<foo::container::iter>, "");
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it with `g++-11 -std=c++20` and it can be compiled successfully.

But if I want to write a reverse iterator for this container, that is, uncomment those code for reverse iterator, there will be a compile error:

```sh
<source>:55:2: error: static_assert failed ""
        static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<foo::container::iter>, "");
        ^                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:55:21: note: because 'foo::container::iter' does not satisfy 'random_access_iterator'
        static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<foo::container::iter>, "");
                           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../include/c++/11.2.0/bits/iterator_concepts.h:669:8: note: because '__n + __j' would be invalid: invalid operands to binary expression ('const iter_difference_t<foo::container::iter>' (aka 'const long') and 'const foo::container::iter')
        { __n +  __j } -> same_as<_Iter>;
              ^
1 error generated.
```

And I also use Clang 13 but got the same result. So how should I write the iterator correctly?

Comment: What part of `because 'foo::container::iter' does not satisfy 'random_access_iterator' ... because '__n + __j' would be invalid: invalid operands to binary expression ('const long' and 'const foo::container::iter')` is unclear? You might want to read up about the [`std::random_access_iterator` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/random_access_iterator)

Comment: There is a definition of `operator+(difference_type, iter)`, but the concept is evaluated before that it's seen. That's why uncommenting code that has nothing to do with the definition of `iter` causes the static_assert to fail. (see my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mystery here is why adding a few lines of code that **don't alter the definition of `foo::container::iter`** causes the `static_assert` to fail.

This is because the implementation of `std::reverse_iterator`'s constructor, in the body of the commented function, evaluates `concept std::random_access_iterator` to determine what sort of reverse iterator to create.

When this happens, `operator+(difference_type, iter)` hasn't been declared yet because **it's further down in your code**, so the your `container::iter` initially fails to satisfy the concept.

Later, you declare the required `operator+` and your type now would satisfy `concept std::random_access_iterator`, were it not for the following part of the standard: [temp.constr.atomic]

> ... If, at different points in the program, the satisfaction result is different for identical atomic constraints and template arguments, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

At different points in your code, the `concept std::random_access_iterator` has different satisfaction results! So your code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. (GCC does actually diagnose this - clang just gives you the error message from when it first evaluated the concept, which is why you were confused).

You can fix this by moving your declaration of operator+ before using `std::reverse_iterator`. For example:

```
struct container {
    struct iter {
        // all your methods, as before
        
        friend iter operator+(difference_type, iter);
    }

    using riter = std::reverse_iterator<iter>;

    iter end();
    riter rbegin();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you give your iterator a `random_access_iterator_tag` category doesn't make it a random access iterator.

You have to provide all the operations.

The compiler error is telling you that the expression `3 + iter_var` is invalid (where `iter_var` is one of your iterators).

The link that Remy provided lists the operations that "have to work".